Cannot find the name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library?
I'm running my project with Vite and it's showing the problem:
Cannot find the name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the compiler option 'lib' to include 'dom'.ts
This is the code:
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from '../src/pages/login'
import Forms from '../src/pages/forms'
import '../src/styles/global.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/forms" element={<Forms />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

What can it be?
I've already tried messing with tsconfig.json but the DOM is already added
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

